# Laravel issue with related models

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables: User, Product and Purchase

```
User: id, email
Product: id, name
Purchase: user_id, product_id, transaction_id
```

In Laravel, I have defined these models:

```
class User extends Authenticatable { 
    //only protected $$fillable and $hidden fields
}

class Product extends Model {
    //only protected $$fillable and $hidden fields
}

class Purchase extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Access\User\User');
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Modules\Product');
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can find out which user has purchased which products so that (in my view) I can loop over all the products and indicate which ones have been purchased already by that user. For these I would present 'watch this product', for all other (not yet purchased products) I want to display 'purchase this product'

I'm currently using the following SQL statement

```
mysql> select p1.product_id, u1.id, p1.stripe_transaction_id  from users u1 right join purchases p1 on u1.id = p1.user_id and u1.id = 4 right join products p2 on p1.product_id = p2.id;

+------------+------+-----------------------+
| product_id | id   | stripe_transaction_id |
+------------+------+-----------------------+
|        100 | NULL | _jbshvScW_8961        |
|        100 | NULL | _zrtdXU_6811          |
|        101 | NULL | _zvgvKS_2536          |
|        102 |    4 | _asgvMP_6811          |
|        103 |    4 | _bffgMXX_6811         |
+------------+------+-----------------------+
```

Then I could loop over the product_ids and everything that is null means not purchased.

But it feels not optimal. Anyone has a better approach to this?

Comment: On which specific area of your logic are you having trouble exactly?

Comment: The required SQL statement to get back all products with an indication if they have been purchased or not.